# why jal main error (jal 0x00000000 [main])

Tags: qtspim

When I run this code,There is an error in the main and it does not operate normally.

I changed the main function or thought there was a problem with the main and global main, so I repeated the correction several times.

```
.data
    message: .asciiz " The final result is "
.text
.global main
main:
    addi $a0, $zero, 3
    addi $a1, $zero, 10
    addi $a2, $zero, 15
    addi $a3, $zero, 7

    jal leaf_example

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, message
    syscall

    li $v0, 1
    syscall

leaf_example:
    addi $sp, $sp,-12
    sw $t1, 8
    sw $t0, 4
    sw $s0, 0
    add $t0,$a0,$a1
    add $t1,$a2,$a3
    sub $s0,$t0,$t1
    add $v0,$s0,$zero
    lw $s0,0
    lw $t0,4
    lw $t1,8
    addi $sp,$sp,12

    jr $ra
```

> spim: (parser) syntax error on line 4 of file
>   C:/Users/user/Desktop/qtspim16.asm   .global main
>             ^